# how to create matrix as in description

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

How to create matrix, output have to looks like:
1, 3, 5, 7, 9 
2, 4, 6, 8, 10
11, 13, 15, 17, 19
20, 22, 24, 26, 28
Expecting for answer on JS, but this is not the point because I`m looking for an algorithm.
Thanks.
I have tried something like this:

```
let arr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  arr[i] = []
  for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    if(j % 2 ==0){
      arr[j] = i
    }
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You should include at least some code of what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see there's a common digit 2 is added each time once you fix the starting point. so here i fixed two starting point one is `even at 2` and another one is `odd at 1`. Now in each iteration increment both values by 2 and add both the `evenArray`  and `oddArray` to final output.

Don't forget to `reset` `evenArray` and `oddArray` after each iteration of inner for loop.

```js
let even = 2;
let odd = 1;
let arr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
  let evenArr = []
  let oddArr = []
  for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++){
    evenArr[j] = even;
    oddArr[j] = odd;
    even +=2;
    odd +=2;
  }
  even = (even-2) * 2;  // to take care of point where even starts with double of last inserted value.
  arr.push(oddArr.join(' '),evenArr.join(' '))
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Work perfect, thanks.

Comment: it does not deliver the last line correctly.

Comment: We should encourage junior developer to write some code before they post their questions here.

Answer (score 2):

First, try to get the building rule

```
                          row   start  comment
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ------ ------ -------------------
  1    3    5    7    9   odd      1
  2    4    6    8   10   even     2
 11   13   15   17   19   odd     10   needs an adjustment
 20   22   24   26   28   even    20
```

Then create an array with the wanted rows and fill it with the value. Swich the start value for each line either with `2` or `5`, depending on the row's index.

Inside of each row take the start value, an adjustment for not even or odd numbers and add the double of the inner index.

```js
var array = Array.from(
        { length: 4 },
        (start => (_, i) => Array.from(
            { length: 5 },
            (v => (_, j) => v + (v % 2 === i % 2) + j * 2)
            (start *= (i % 2 ? 2 : 5))
        ))
        (0.2)
    );

console.log(array.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```